# Is it possible to create a session on python cmd library?

Tags: python, session-variables, command-line-arguments

I need to create a session to handle objects and parameters given by command and when it is committed i will parse this session object into json or insert database. Is there any way to work like this?

Suppose that:

```
cmd:~$ start -session
New session started with PID:12312313
cmd:~$ add -object stackoverflow
Session variable stackoverflow created
cmd:~$ add -param foo -t stackoverflow
New param foo added to stackoverflow object
cmd:~$ commit -s 123123123
Session 123123123 committed to the database. Congrats.
```

This is how i dream it should process. Is there anyone assist to make this work?

Comment: Could you please give details on what you mean by "session" ? Whithout knowing the application context it's pretty hard to guess what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some work to do to fulfill your dream, but it seems achievable yes!

For the command line interface I've had much success with the [pyCLI](http://packages.python.org/pyCLI/) module.

It helps a lot in structuring your application. You'll then end up filling up hooks to store temporary objects in variables and commit to the database.

For handling the database interface, there are a [number of options](http://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html) out there. A simple working solution might be implemented using [DBM](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dbm.html).

Comment: thanks for your response. I already deal with cmd library to handle my command line interface. All i need to create a runtime session. I do all other things such database operations.